# Using Contains() list method to evaluate list contents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, find, contains

I have a list that contains 3 items, two of type_1, and one of type_2.  I want to return a second list that contains the type and number of that type that exists.  When stepping through the breakpoints set at the foreach loop, the IF statement is never true.  I assume there is something wrong with my attempt to use Contains() method.

The output should be something like:

```
 type_1    2
 type_2    1
```

Instead, it evaluates as:

```
 type_1    1
 type_1    1
 type_2    1
```

Is my use of Contains() not correct?

```
public List<item_count> QueryGraphListingsNewAccountReport()

  List<item> result = new List<items>();

  var type_item1 = new item { account_type = "Type_1" };
  var type_item2 = new item { account_type = "Type_1" };
  var type_item3 = new item { account_type = "Type_2" };

  result.Add(type_item1);
  result.Add(type_item2);
  result.Add(type_item3);

 //Create a empty list that will hold the account_type AND a count of how many of that type exists:

  List<item_count> result_count = new List<item_count>();

  foreach (var item in result)
  {  
  if (result_count.Contains(new item_count { account_type = item.account_type, count = 1 } ) == true)
   {
     var result_item = result_count.Find(x => x.account_type == item.account_type);
     result_item.count += 1;
     result_count.Add(result_item);
   }
   else
   {
     var result_item = new item_count { account_type = item.account_type, count = 1 };
     result_count.Add(result_item);
   }   
  }
  return result_count;
}

public class item
{
    public string account_type { get; set; }
}
public class item_count    
{
    public int count {get; set;}
    public string account_type { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't want to use contains at all. You are creating a new object in your contains statement and, obviously, it isn't contained in your list already because you only just created it. The comparison is comparing references, not values.

Why not just use the find statement that you do in the next line instead? If it returns null, then you know there isn't an item already with that type.

So you could do something like this:

```
var result_item = result_count.Find(x => x.account_type == item.account_type);
if (result_item != null) 
{
    result_item.count++;
    // note here you don't need to add it back to the list!
}
else
{
    // create your new result_item here and add it to your list.
}
```

**Note**: Find is o(n), so this might not scale well if you have a really large set of types. In that case, you might be better off with Saeed's suggestion of grouping.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much! For the time being, I'll use this method as this is currently just a proof of concept, so the scale is fairly small, but I'll look into implementing Saeed's linq usage later

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
myList.GroupBy(x=>x.type).Select(x=>new {x.Key, x.Count()});
```

If you want use for loop, it's better to use linq `Count` function to achieve this, If you want use Contains you should implement equal operator as the way you used.